# Geometric Sum from n to infinity of -1/2

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I want to calculate the Sum from k=n to infinity for (-1/2)^k

But n can be either odd so we have:

-1/2, 1/4, -1/8, 1/16 ....

Either even:

1/2, -1/4, 1/8, -1/16 ....

In order to have a two branch function y(n) that given the n will find the Sum.

Please explain me the solution.

I have started working on a solution of my own but because I haven't learnt to write mathematic symbols, it will be hard to write and hard to read the final text.

Comment: one way to do this is to split $\sum_{k=0}^\infty = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} + \sum_{k=n}^\infty$ and find the left piece and the finite piece separately

Comment: This is an ordinary [Geometric Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=n}^\infty \bigg (-\frac12 \bigg)^k &= \bigg (-\frac12 \bigg)^n\sum_{k=0}^\infty \bigg (-\frac12 \bigg)^k \\
&= \bigg (-\frac12 \bigg)^n\cdot \frac23 \\
&= \frac{(-1)^n}{3} \cdot 2^{1-n}
\end{align*}